# htmlparser2 convert xml object into string

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, parsing

I'm having a little trouble getting the [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) module (using node.js) to output an xml string. Basically I'm parsing it in like so:

```
var htmlparser=require('htmlparser2');
function(xmlString,cb){
    var handler=new htmlparser.DomHandler(cb);
    var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
    parser.write(xmlString);
    parser.done();
}
```

Then I get an object called "dom", which I do some work on. After that work is done, I want to export it back into an XML string. I know that `htmlparser.DomUtils.getOuterHTML(dom)` works for HTML objects, but doesn't work for XML (at least not by default). I get back `<undefined></undefined>` when I call `htmlparser.DomUtils.getOuterHTML(dom)` on an xml dom.

Thanks in advance for any help you're able to offer!
-Dylan

Comment: Fixed. Basically you need to use a second option in getOuterHTML...
htmlparser.DomUtils.getOuterHTML(dom,{xmlMode:true})
If that doesn't work, try calling on the inner elems in the array like:
htmlparser.DomUtils.getOuterHTML(dom[0],{xmlMode:true})
You'll have to wrap a for loop around it to get the whole document, but it works for me!

Answer (score 4):

Fixed. Basically you need to use a second option in getOuterHTML...

```
htmlparser.DomUtils.getOuterHTML(dom,{xmlMode:true})
```

If that doesn't work, try calling on the inner elems in the array like:

```
htmlparser.DomUtils.getOuterHTML(dom[0],{xmlMode:true})
```

You'll have to wrap a for loop around it to get the whole document, but it works for me!

Comment: Thanks for sharing! `Domutils` still has no documentation, anything helps..